# Enlarge text/image on hover/focus (bubble-up / fisheye ?)

Tags: jquery, focus, hover, image-enlarge

The desired effect is what seems to be termed as/similar to Bubble-up or FishEye examples:

- http://aext.net/2010/04/bubbleup-jquery-plugin/
- http://interface.eyecon.ro/demos/fisheye.html

I've seen a few examples/plugins, but all had issues/limitations the most notable ones being:

- Not keyboard accessible Requires
- Preset height/width Affects
- Preceeding/following items/elements
- Browser compatibility issues

I have tweaked some of the existing examples but I get the distinct impression that it isn't as streamlined as it ought to be, and that there are little bugs with it's behaviour.

Ideally the following will work;
1) It will permit a scale for enlargement
2) It will permit you to specify any element to be affected
3) It will handle Height/Width/other properties automatically
4) It will manage if a property is not present/empty
5) It will not affect surrounding/preceding elements (positioned absolute whilst leaving clone/holder element)

Here's the code I have so far:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
$(document).ready(function() {

// NOTE: the element to become enlarged must have a z-index value!  (even if you set it as 1)
$(function(){
  function fatOnHover($elements, zoomSize, animationSpeed){
  $elements.each(function(i){
     var $wrap, height, width, left, bigWidth, bigHeight, $that = $(this);

  // Get the item height/width, and create the enlarged dimensions
     height = $that.height();
     width = $that.width();
  bigWidth = (width / 100) * zoomSize;
     bigHeight = (height / 100) * zoomSize;

  // Calculate the positioning (negative pull) based on the size difference of normal to enlarged
  left = (bigWidth - width) / 2;
  top = (bigHeight - height) / 2;

  // Addition for Text enlargening (gets font-size and sets enlarged font-size) (should accept any measurement (px/em etc.))
  //currFontSize = $that.css("font-size");
  //fontSize = parseFloat(currFontSize, 10);
  //fontEnding = currFontSize.slice(-2);
  //bigfontsize = (fontSize / 100) * zoomSize;

  // Get and Set the z-index = MUST make sure the item to be enlarged has a z-index (even if set to 1)
  // Ideally - should detect if there is a value, if not, set one
  currzindex = parseInt($that.css('z-index'));
  //currzindex = 100;
  zindexoffset = 900;
  bigZindex = currzindex + zindexoffset;



  // Insert div before/around the item to be enlarged (and to the same height/width)
      $wrap = "<div style='width: " + width + "px; height: " + height + "px; position: relative;'></div>",

   // Actually - no idea what all of this is for :D
      $that.data({"width": width, "height": height, "bigWidth": bigWidth, "bigHeight": bigHeight, "left": left, "top": top, /*"fontSize": fontSize, "bigfontsize": bigfontsize, "fontEnding": fontEnding,*/ "currzindex": currzindex, "bigZindex": bigZindex})
          .wrap($wrap)
   })

   // Define function/behavious for focus/hover
   .bind('mouseenter mouseover focus',
     function(){
        var $that = $(this);
        $that.stop().css('z-index', $that.data("bigZindex")).animate({"width": $that.data("bigWidth"), "height": $that.data("bigHeight"), "left": -$that.data("left"), "top": -$that.data("top")/*, "fontSize": $that.data("bigfontsize")+$that.data("fontEnding")*/}, animationSpeed);
     })

   // Define function/behavious for loss of focus/hover (normal)
 .bind('mouseleave mouseout blur',
     function(){
        var $that = $(this);
        $that.stop().css('z-index', $that.data("currzindex")).animate({"width": $that.data("width"), "height": $that.data("height"), "left": '0', "top": '0'/*, "fontSize": $that.data("fontSize")+$that.data("fontEnding")*/}, animationSpeed);
     })

  // Assigns position absolute to item to be enlarged
  .css("position", "absolute")
   }
   fatOnHover($('#nav li a'), 135, 900);
})

});
//]]>
</script>
```

I have commented out some of the code (such as the font-size stuff).
That is due to one of the "bugs" I have.

I think I've done it right to work with keyboard/mouse.
I think I've managed to handle some of the additional properties (such as z-index and font-size) - but only up to a point

Issues.
1) The script requires the item to be affected to have a z-index defined.
Is it possible for this to be checked for, and if no z-index is defined, the script to set one?
2) Font resizing seems to cause issues - the resized text on hover is huge, not what I would have assumed as "to scale" (I set the fs as em, resize the text, and it's massive on hover, and doesn't return to normal-size after hover)
3) The code seems bloated?  I'm assuming there are better ways of doing some of this stuff.
4) Speed for animation in and animation out - is it possible?

Comment: Thank you for making them links :casperOne: :D

Answer (score 0):

The first problem I see is that you have a DOM ready event inside of a DOM ready event.

Here's my version of your code with optimizations commented.  I've introduced more local variables to clean up the global scope.  I've removed Hungarian notation, but you can put it back in if you like:

```
//<![CDATA[
    $(function() {
        var fatOnHover = function(elements, zoomSize, animationSpeed) {
            elements.each(function() {
                var wrap, options, tempZ, currFontSize, zindexoffset = 900, element = $(this);
                tempZ = element.css('z-index');
                currFontSize = element.css('font-size')
                options = {
                    height : element.height(),
                    width : element.width(),
                    fontSize : parseFloat(currFontSize, 10),
                    fontEnding : currFontSize.slice(-2),
                    currzindex : (tempZ === undefined || tempZ === 'auto') ? 100 : parseInt(tempZ)
                };
                $.extend(options, {
                    bigWidth : (options.width / 100) * zoomSize,
                    bigHeight : (options.height / 100) * zoomSize,
                    bigZindex : options.currzindex + zindexoffset,
                    bigfontsize : (options.fontSize / 100) * zoomSize
                });
                $.extend(options, {
                    left : (options.bigWidth - options.width) / 2,
                    top : (options.bigHeight - options.height) / 2
                });

                wrap = ['<div style="height:',options.height,'px;width:',options.width,'px;position:relative;"></div>'].join('');
                element.data(options).wrap(wrap);
            })
            // Define function/behavious for focus/hover
            .bind('mouseenter mouseover focus', function() {
                var element = $(this);
                element
                    .css('z-index', element.data('bigZindex'))
                    .stop()
                    .animate({
                        'width':element.data('bigWidth'),
                        'height':element.data('bigHeight'),
                        'left':-element.data('left'),
                        'top':-element.data('top'),
                        'fontSize':[
                            element.data('bigfontsize'),
                            element.data('fontEnding')
                        ].join('')
                    }, animationSpeed);
            })
            // Define function/behavious for loss of focus/hover (normal)
            .bind('mouseleave mouseout blur',
                function() {
                    var element = $(this);
                    element
                        .css('z-index', element.data('currzindex'))
                        .stop()
                        .animate({
                            'width':element.data('width'),
                            'height':element.data('height'),
                            'left':'0',
                            'top':'0',
                            'fontSize':[
                                element.data('fontSize'),
                                element.data('fontEnding')
                            ].join('')
                        }, animationSpeed);
            })
            // Assigns position absolute to item to be enlarged
            .css('position', 'absolute')
        };
        fatOnHover($('#nav li a'), 200, 100);
    });
    //]]>
```

The above code animates text no problem.  Tested in FF, Chrome and IE7.

Comment: looks much tidier, and seems less clunky - but I'm not sure if I've done something wrong - as the wrapping div doesn't seem to have a Height/Width?  (wondering if I broke it already).

Comment: '<div style="height:',height,';width:', width,
';position:relative;"></div>'
vs
'<div style="height:',height,'px;width:',width,'px',
';position:relative;"></div>'

Is that the correct way of doing it?  (seems to work, but no idea if that's the right/wrong way or not (I'd hate to be putting "hungarian" back in it (what is that anyway?))
All the same - very much appreciated - at least the code now makes sense when I look at it :D

Comment: Anyone/Anything else?  
Resizing Text (not zoom!) results in strange text size to container ratios ... is it because I tend to use EMs?
Would adding in detection of Padding and including that in sizing help?

Basically - I think this could become more than al ittle useful - as is it's better than the few examples I saw ... and now it's tidier, leaner and seems a little faster ... so what else can be done?

Comment: I only tested with pixels and resizing had no negative effect that I could see.

Comment: Not sure what changed, but I'm calling/using this as a function inside another call - and I have to change the ending " });" to " })" for it to work now (no big deal, just took a second to figure it :D

The Resize bug:
Load page - hover ... things are fine ... text enlarges, then reverts to original size (px or em).
Resize text in browser (not zoom!) - then reload page - hover, things expand.in FireFox 3, the revert size is wrong (about halfway between the original and the enlarged size, doesn't go all the way back to what it should).

IE7 + Chrome7 are fine.Jsut FireFox (3) that seems wrong?

Comment: I've insert alert() calls (below the font-settings, then after each animation call).  
The sizes reported are correct, start, enlarge and revert are all correct - just FF3 seems to display it incorrectly.

Comment: Hmmm - I stand corrected.
What ever revision you made is causing errors .... Options.fontSize undefined?

Comment: Ooops.  That's what I get for not testing it.  Moved the offending code from the first extend to the second one.